# Running Ubuntu Eclipse C++ Helloworld

Tags: c++, eclipse, ubuntu

I'm trying to run a Hello world C++ on Eclipse on Ubuntu 12.04. I installed g++ and wrote this code:

```
#include<vector>
#include<string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Compile output:

```
**** Build of configuration Debug for project TopCoder ****

make all 
make: Nothing to be done for `all'.

**** Build Finished ****
```

Run output message:

```
Launching TopCoder has encountered a problem
Error starting process

Error starting process.
Exec_tty error:Cannot run program "/media/01CCE00FA6888D80/Achieve/Eclipse/TopCoder/Debug/TopCoder": Unknown reason
Exec_tty error:Cannot run program "/media/01CCE00FA6888D80/Achieve/Eclipse/TopCoder/Debug/TopCoder": Unknown reason
Exec_tty error:Cannot run program "/media/01CCE00FA6888D80/Achieve/Eclipse/TopCoder/Debug/TopCoder": Unknown reason
```

when I put the source code on ext4 drive it builds and run
I changed

```
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
```

in /etc/fstab to

```
proc            /proc           proc    dev,exec,suid 0       0
```

But no usefulness.

Comment: Are you able to run this from the command line?

Comment: Off topic: You don't need to `return 0;` in `main` in C++.

Comment: You problem might be similar to [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1081076).

Answer (score 4):

You're tring to run an application from the `/media/01CCE00FA6888D80` volume. Removable USB? The most likely culprit is  `noexec` as an option to the default mount command line.

check if `noexec` is part of the options for mounting the filesystem using:

```
grep noexec /proc/mounts
```

if this results in output indicating that `noexec` is in effect for the file system then try:

```
sudo mount -o remount,exec /media/01CCE00FA6888D80
```

Also, if the removable volume is NTFS, your milage may vary.

Answer (score 0):

Try to build it from the command line. Then you will know if the problem is involved with g++ or with eclipse. I guess you should change your compiler path somewhere in the eclipse, are you sure you have eclipse-cdt? THe easiest way to compile it is:

> g++ yourfile.cpp

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're workspace is probably on a different drive than the one you installed ubuntu on

Answer (score 0):

You are running you project over Linux . i  had facing same issue when my project was in my E drive  . i gave read -write permission but still  that was not enough for me . The same error was keep coming when i was trying to run the project .

I have shifted my project in my Home folder ,gave  permission  and the project ran !! .

I  believe there was a problem with some permission for LINUX  C compiler .